# How to pass an array into getElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, websocket

I'm passing data from my websocket into an array. I will like to pass the array into `document.getElementById`. Eventually I will like to display my data in a `div`. I'm getting `null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML')`

**JavaScript**

```
socket.on('data_added', function(mess){


console.log(mess);
var x  =[];
x.push(mess);
console.log(x);

   var  datetime = [];
   var  humidity = [];
   var  temp = [];
    for(var i =0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        datetime.push(x[i].datetime);
        humidity.push(x[i].humidity)
        temp.push(x[i].temperature)
    }



   temp =  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML ;
    humidity = document.getElementById('humidity').innerHTML;

    console.log(datetime);
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(humidity);
});
```

**my data**
`[{datetime: "2017-01-09T02:07:38.490Z", temperature: 19, humidity: 23}]`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: assignment in javascript works the other way around ... destination = source ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwed exception means that you have no tag on your page with id 'temp'.
I think that you need to write smth like that:

```js
socket.on('data_added', function(x){
  if(typeof x === "string") {
   x = JSON.parse(x);
  }

  var  datetime = [];
  var  humidity = [];

  for(var i =0; i < x.length; i++) {
    datetime.push(x[i].datetime);
    humidity.push(x[i].humidity)
  }

  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = datetime ;
  document.getElementById('humidity').innerHTML = humidity;

  console.log(datetime);
  console.log(humidity);
});
```

```html
<div id="temp"></div>
<div id="humidity"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I worked with a little modification.